# meta_query not working as expected

Tags: wp-query, functions, meta-query

I have 3 posts that each have two meta values. The first meta value is one that they all share (`ac_parent_event`). The second is one that is unique to that post (`ac_thischild_date`). For this function, I am trying to query one post by both of the meta values. 
The query I have, as far as I know, should return the one post that has both values set to the values specified in the variables, but instead this returns the THREE posts that have the 'ac_parent_event' value, even though all three have different `ac_thischild_date` values.
I've also tried using `'LIKE'` instead of `'='` with the same result.
I've verified that `$date` and `$parent_id` are being passed successfully.

```
function ac_get_event_id_by_date($date, $parent_id) {
$matches = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'post_status' => array('draft', 'pending', 'publish'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'ac_thischild_date',
        'value' => $date,
        'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
        'key' => 'ac_parent_event',
        'value' => $parent_id,
        'compare' => '=',
        )
    ),
));
    foreach ($matches as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        global $post;
        $chPost_id = get_the_ID();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $chPost_id;
}
```

Comment: for debugging purposes, it's easier to use `WP_Query`, then you can `var_dump` the query object and inspect the query vars and SQL request to see what's going on.